# rel attribute in anchor tag

Tags: html

If i give `<a href="some_link" rel="">` will the search engine consider rel="" to be noindex, nofollow?

Answer (score 2):

No. They won't. This is just a space separated list of relationships consisting of zero items.

Note that the 'nofollow' relationship does not mean "Do not follow this link", it means "Do not consider this link to be an endorsement of this URL".

There is no commonly accepted 'noindex' relationship. You are probably confusing the rel attribute with the meta robots directive (which should generally be avoided in favour of a simple robots.txt anyway).